# Site-Map on CQ-5 (AEM) is rendering child pages even after the "show page in siteMap" is deselected

Tags: aem

I have run into an issue when I deselect "show page in site map" it takes off the parent page but still renders its children.

[image]

Now I am assuming it is a simple boolean check to see if "site map" is selected in the Page properties. However I am not sure what that variable is called if that is the solution.

Here is how I am rendering it to the page:

private void printChildren(Page currentPage,JspWriter writer, List extraCategoryList)throws IOException{
        boolean childPagePrinted=false;
        Page categoryPage = null;

```
Iterator<Page> childIterator = currentPage.listChildren();
while(childIterator.hasNext()) {

    Page childPage = childIterator.next();
    if(childPage.getProperties().get("showInSitemap") != null){

      if(childPage.getProperties().get("sitemapcategory") != null){
          extraCategoryList.add(childPage);
      }else{

        if(!childPagePrinted){
            writer.print("<ul>");
            childPagePrinted=true;
        }
        String pageHtml = getPageHtml(childPage);
        writer.print(pageHtml);   
      }
    }
    printChildren(childPage,writer,extraCategoryList);

}

if(childPagePrinted){
       writer.print("</ul>");
}
```

}

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your loop, you still call printChildren(childPage,writer,extraCategoryList);
You need to move this line in the if(childPage.getProperties().get("showInSitemap") != null)

right now it still calls it no matter what is selected.
So it should be like this:
    Iterator childIterator = currentPage.listChildren();
    while(childIterator.hasNext()) {

```
    Page childPage = childIterator.next();
    if(childPage.getProperties().get("showInSitemap") != null){

        if(childPage.getProperties().get("sitemapcategory") != null){
            extraCategoryList.add(childPage);
        }else{

            if(!childPagePrinted){
                writer.print("<ul>");
                childPagePrinted=true;
            }
            String pageHtml = getPageHtml(childPage);
            writer.print(pageHtml);
        }
        // print the childs if we're printing the parent
        printChildren(childPage,writer,extraCategoryList);
    }

}

if(childPagePrinted){
    writer.print("</ul>");
}
```

Comment: Not sure what more to say, your initial code had an error in its logic where it would call printChildren regardless if the parent was displayed or not because it was outside of the if statement.  At this point I would change your output to display the values of the showInSitemap properties as well as additional info to see why it would still display them.  Because logically it should not happen anymore if you moved the printChildren inside the 1st if statement.